# iOS5 Address Book Text Field

Tags: ios, ios5, components

I need to do a component text field like the Address Book. How I do it?

The left part is a button, the right part is a tex field.

Example:

[image: example image showing a field with a label]

Comment: Are you sure the left part is a button? It doesn't behave like one on my iPhone...

Comment: When I touch the left part, it highlight and open a new View

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that draws itself with rounded corners and draws the vertical line that separates the two halves. Add a button without a border as a subview of the left part; add a text field without a border as a subview of the right part.

Drawing the rounded corners is simple: just set the `cornerRadius` property of the view's layer:

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking something like reuse the Address Book component, but I will have to do your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as a table cell then you can use the cell style

```
UITableViewCellStyleValue2
```

> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with text that is right-aligned and blue; on the right side of the cell is another label with smaller text that is left-aligned and black. The Phone/Contacts application uses cells in this style.

From [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Other wise you can just create a text field and set a label as leftView. Like Caleb already said use cornerRadius property to get rounded corners.